# How to deploy webpart on production (not debugging) server?

Tags: web-part, deployment, production

I've created a web part, debugging it on a test Sharepoint 2010 install on my local workstation. I'd like to test it on our production server. It seems that I won't be able to use Build --> Deploy to accomplish this, and I have to deal with my assembly and .webpart file.

What are the steps to accomplish this?

Comment: You test it on a test/integration/acceptance server, not a production server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SharePoint solution packages consist of a **.WSP** file that you can create using Visual Studio (or manually if you so wish).

Before deploying to a production environment, I recommend you take a look through [Deploy solution packages (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262995.aspx#deploying).

Basically you need to add your solution to the solution database of a SharePoint Server farm using the **Add-SPSolution** PowerShell cmdlet, then deploy the solution using either Central Administration or the **Install-SPSolution** PowerShell cmdlet.

Both installation options above provide a choice of installing to either a single Web application, or all Web applications.

Comment: hahaha, we both answered the question with the same link. I'm whacking mine...you beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 4):

The deploy action creates a .WSP file in your bin\debug or bin\release folder...depending on what you built. You can use that file to deploy the solution...everything you need should be in that package assuming the package was built correctly.

MSDN reference on deployment here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262995.aspx

Comment: there is nothing wrong with multiple answers, even if they are the same (especially since we try to improve our answer/question ratio on Area51 so we can get out of beta;-)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can create some `.bat` files and then run them from command prompt as Administrator:

**1. Add.bat**

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN\stsadm.exe" -o addsolution -filename "C:\YourSolution.wsp"

"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN\stsadm.exe" -o deploysolution -name "YourSolution.wsp" -immediate -url http://YourDomain -allowgacdeployment -allowcaspolicies
```

**2. Retract.bat**

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN\stsadm.exe" -o retractsolution -name "YourSolution.wsp" -immediate -allcontenturls
```

**3. Delete.bat**

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN\stsadm.exe" -o deletesolution -name YourSolution.wsp
```

Additional resources:

[Index for Stsadm operations and properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263384%28office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: I think powershell command are best practice and more flexiple to add custom commands to deploy scripts as well.

Comment: What's wrong with STSADM? Where does it say powershell is a best practice?

Comment: @Kit Menke "In the SharePoint administration context, Windows PowerShell supersedes the Stsadm.exe administration tool. All current and future development of script and administrative files in SharePoint Foundation should use this new Windows PowerShell scripting technology that is exposed in the SharePoint Management Shell." - Sharepoint Foundation 2010 SDK Documentation

Comment: Ah! Very cool, I found this link too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539977.aspx